# Variable in while loop only check on initial execution?

Tags: shell-script, variable

I've written this script expecting that it will run the given commands while the variable is less than the value. But whats happening (per the logs) when the script is initially executed, it checks the variable "TEMP_NOW" and uses that initial value forever - like its being cached. I have confirmed the variable TEMP_NOW is definitely changing.

Thanks for looking

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x
LOG_FILE=/home/mutt/pl/logs/pump.log
TEMP_NOW=$(cat /home/mutt/pl/logs/temp_now.txt)

while [ $TEMP_NOW -le 556 ]
do
        /home/mutt/pl/temp_pump_on.s
        echo ON > /home/mutt/pl/logs/pump_sch.txt
        echo $TEMP_NOW at `$(which date)` >> $LOG_FILE 2>&1 &
        sleep 5m
        /home/mutt/pl/temp_pump_off.s
        echo $TEMP_NOW at `$(which date)` >> $LOG_FILE 2>&1 &
        echo OFF > /home/mutt/pl/logs/pump_sch.txt
        sleep 20m
set +x 
done
```

Logs:

```
mutt@mutt:~/pl/logs $ tail -10 pump.log
TEMP turned pump off at Sat Jan 13 13:07:01 CST 2018
125 at Sat Jan 13 13:07:01 CST 2018
TEMP turned pump ON at Sat Jan 13 13:27:01 CST 2018
125 at Sat Jan 13 13:27:01 CST 2018
TEMP turned pump off at Sat Jan 13 13:32:01 CST 2018
125 at Sat Jan 13 13:32:01 CST 2018 
TEMP turned pump ON at Sat Jan 13 13:52:01 CST 2018
125 at Sat Jan 13 13:52:01 CST 2018
125 at Sat Jan 13 13:57:01 CST 2018
TEMP turned pump off at Sat Jan 13 13:57:01 CST 2018
mutt@mutt:~/pl/logs $ ll temp_now.txt 
-rw-rw-rw- 1 pi pi 5 Jan 13 14:12 temp_now.txt
mutt@mutt:~/pl/logs $ cat temp_now.txt 
9625
mutt@mutt:~/pl/logs $
```

Comment: "I have confirmed the variable TEMP_NOW is definitely changing." You have a completely wrong understanding of how variables work. You kind of mix up variables with shell functions (output).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course, the variable is static, it is never assigned to inside the loop, replace:

```
while [ $TEMP_NOW -le 556 ]
```

with:

```
while [ "$(cat /home/mutt/pl/logs/temp_now.txt)" -le 556 ]
```

so that the file is re-read on every loop.

Comment: Thanks isaac - 
I don't think I'm going to quit my day job anytime soon...